# How can I ensure that all of my internet traffic uses my OpenVPN, even after reboot?

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn, ufw

I would like to allow my PC to communicate to all LAN devices (10.0.0.0/24) but only allow traffic outside of my network to use my ExpressVPN connection.

ExpressVPN does not provide a list of IPs so I will also need to allow DNS and 1195 UDP to establish the VPN connection.

I have been trying to use ufw but I'm worried my rules are incorrect or will allow leaks. I'm over my head, but trying to learn.

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw --force reset
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow out on tun0
sudo ufw allow out on enp2s0 to any port 53,67,68,1195 proto udp
sudo ufw allow in on enp2s0 from 10.0.0.0/24
```

Comment: How do you connect to your VPN usually? Using a *.ovpn config file?

Comment: Correct, they have provided a preconfigured *.ovpn file

Comment: And does that config file contain the IP(s) of the servers it connects to? If so, you can add those IPs to your ufw config.

Comment: check their [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207250/how-can-i-ensure-that-all-of-my-internet-traffic-uses-my-openvpn-even-after-reb) how to use it with terminal, secondly I wouldn't recommend using ufw and vpn you will constantly face into troubles with connection interruption.